# Вывод пола человека на страницу?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Вот моя модель данных:

```
 public partial class People
    {
        public int PeopleID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SecondName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> BirthDay { get; set; }
        public byte[] ProfileImage { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> Sex { get; set; }
    }
```

Задаю пол человека 0 - это жен., 1 - это муж.
Снизу вид.

```
  @using (Ajax.BeginForm(ajax))
        {
            <table class="table table-responsive">
                <thead><tr><td>Фамилия</td><td>Имя</td><td>Пол</td></tr></thead>
                <tbody id="personList">
                    @Html.Action("GetPersons", new { sexType = ViewBag.PersonType })
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <p>@Html.DropDownList("sexType", new SelectList
```

(new[] { "Все", "Женщины", "Мужчины" }), new { onchange = "$(this.form).submit();" })

}

плюс partial страничка выглядит так

```
@using Test4.Models
@model IEnumerable<Test4.Models.People>
@{
    Layout = null;
}
@foreach (var person in Model)
{
    <tr><td>@person.SecondName</td><td>@person.Name</td><td>@person.Sex</td></tr>
}
```

И вот сам контроллер

```
 public ActionResult GetPersons(string sexType)
    {
        int sex = 2;
        if (sexType == "Женщины")
        {
            sex = 0;
        }
        else if(sexType == "Мужчины")
        {
            sex = 1;
        }
        var result = sex == 2 ? db.Peoples : db.Peoples.Where(x => x.Sex == sex); 
        return View(result.ToList());
    }
```

Выбора работает все ок. Если есть мысли как оптимизировать контроллер буду рад. Но вот в чем проблема, как мне выводить на экран не цифры, а уже описание какой пол у человека.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вкратце, то:

1. Используйте на странице следующую модель и заполняйте ее в контроллере:

`Public class PageViewModel {
    public List<People> Peoples {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<Gender> Categories {get; set}
    public int SelectedGender {get; set;}
   }`

2. `@model PageViewModel;`
3. Из `@Html.DropDownList` в контроллер передавайте код выбранного пола, а не название.

`var genders = _dal.GetGenderCategories();
 var pageViewModel = new PageViewModel { 
 Categories = genders.Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = c.Id.ToString(),
            Text = c.Name
        })`

View:

`@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.SelectedGender,
    new SelectList(Model.Categories, "Value", "Text")
)`

4. для вывода типа пола в виде названия можно сделать razor функцию или же сделать в классе People свойство, которое будет генерить имя из кода, например:

`....
 public string Gender { get {return sexType == 0? "женщина" : "мужчина";}}
...`